# How to show a div in JS underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js-templating

I am using `$.getJSON` in a jquery script to get data from a php file and display it in a template(underscore).

My template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="user-template">

<% _.each(users, function(user){%>
            <div class="id"><%=user.id%> </div>
            <div class="name"><%= user.name %></div>
            <div class="city"><%= user.city %></div><br />
    <% }); %>

</script>
```

My script:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
        var results = userTemplate({ users: data.users}),
        $("#theresults").html(results);}
```

On each page im listing 10 users (or 10 results). The code works fine. I want to be able to show another div after every 4 results. Like an ad or a promotional content.

`<div id="mycustomdiv">Custom DIV</div>`

How do i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: From what i see you just need some variable that will save iteration number. And than inside each just do something like this if (yourVar != 0 && yourVar % 4 == 0) {add div here.} yourVar++; But if you have users as an array just use index from underscore second argument.

Comment: you can do it just before attaching the new content to DOM, i.e. before `$("#theresults").html(results);` statement; modify the `results` variable as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the second argument of the callback function to determine the current index

```
 <% _.each(users, function(user, index){%>
        <div class="id"><%=user.id%> </div>
        <div class="name"><%= user.name %></div>
        <div class="city"><%= user.city %></div><br />
        <% if(index !== 0 && (index % 4) === 0) { %>
           <div id="mycustomdiv">Custom DIV</div>
        <% } %>
 <% }); %>
```

Comment: One slight correction... This will show the mycustomdiv on the first result as well.

<% if (index+1 % 4 === 0) { %>

Comment: depends if he wants to show it or not on the first result

Comment: @oliv37 thank you.. thank you .. thank you .. thank you .. thank you .. thanks a ton!!!

Comment: @Chazzu .. thanks mate .. your suggestion is exactly what i need!